# How to Figure Out the Regular Expression

Tags: regex, syntax, compiler-construction, tree

I know that there is a way to figure out the regular expression yourself based on tree you build. For example, you can build the tree that represent all cases of complex numbers (i.e., a+bi, bi+a, ...), then based on the built tree, you can find out the regular expression for complex numbers. This method is part of building compiler for syntax analysis. However, I do not remember how it was done. Can anyone help with examples?

Comment: Regular expressions are sometimes used for the scanner/tokenizer. But the parser part of a compiler usually uses (E)BNF grammar or the same in code (recursive descent).  A regex can't properly match nested expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I have found it. The tree is called Parse Tree. See the following link:
[Compiler Design - Syntax Analysis](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_syntax_analysis.htm)

However, it seems writing a regular expression straight away is easier. I think this can be used to build a procedure to validate an expression without using Regex class.